# In LR parsing, is it possible to construct a non-binary AST?

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, yacc, lr-grammar

I am currently trying to build a parser for propositional logic using the Python SLY module. SLY is a Python implementation of lex and yacc.

https://sly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sly.html#introduction

The documentation says, "SLY provides no special functions for constructing an abstract syntax tree. However, such construction is easy enough to do on your own." This is what I am trying to do. In their example code, they recommend doing this by defining your own data structure for tree nodes, and using it in the grammar rules.

```
class BinOp(Expr):
    def __init__(self, op, left, right)
        self.op = op
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class Number(Expr):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

@_('expr PLUS expr',
   'expr MINUS expr',
   'expr TIMES expr',
   'expr DIVIDE expr')
def expr(self, p):
    return BinOp(p[1], p.expr0, p.expr1)

@_('LPAREN expr RPAREN')
def expr(self, p):
    return p.expr
```

My problem is that for my application of parsing propositional logic, although this way of parsing would correctly check syntax and represent the meaning of the logic expression parsed, the parser would construct the AST as a binary tree. Hence, if I were to let it parse the following two expressions:

1. pvqvr
2. pv(qvr)

The resulting ASTs would look the same (with right associativity).

For a different part of my project, it is important for me to treat conjunction and disjunction operations as n-ary rather than binary. Taking the first expression above as an example, the disjunction operation is being applied to the three operands p, q, and r simultaneously. I will need to be able to distinguish between the two example expressions above by just looking at the AST itself. The following diagrams show the difference I am going after

```
            v                  v
         /  |  \              / \
         p  q  r             p   v
                                / \
                                q r
```

Is it theoretically possible with LR parsing to create ASTs with nodes that have more than two children? If so, is the SLY framework robust enough for me to be able to do this, or do I need to create my own parser? If LR parsing is incapable of creating such a tree, are there other algorithms I should consider? I am not doing any further compiling after creating the tree, I just need to form trees that represent propositional logic expressions as indicated above.

Apologies in advance if it's a stupid question, I just took Programming Languages and Translators in the Spring 2020 semester, and with everything that's been going on in the world, the learning experience was rather disruptive. I would greatly appreciate any advice. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Certainly you can do it. It's just playing around with data structures, after all. However, it's tricky (though certainly not impossible) to cover all the cases while you're parsing, so it may be easier (and more efficient) to transform the tree after the parse is complete.

The key problem is that when you are parsing `expr OR expr`, it is possible that either or both `expr` non-terminals are already `OR` nodes, whose lists need to be combined. So you might start with something like this:

```py
class BinOp(Expr):
    def __init__(self, op, left, right)
        if left.op == op:
             left_ops = left.operands
        else:
             left_ops = (left,)
        if right.op == op:
             right_ops = right.operands
        else:
             right_ops = (right,)
        self.op = op
        self.operands = left_ops + right_ops

@_('expr OR expr',
   'expr AND expr')
def expr(self, p):
    return BinOp(p[1], p.expr0, p.expr1)
```

That will work. But here's my suspicion (because it's happened to me, over and over again with different variations): at some point you'll want to apply deMorgan's laws (perhaps not consistently, but in some cases), so you'll end up turning some negated conjunction nodes into disjunctions and/or negated disjunction nodes in conjunctions. And after you do that, you'll want to compress the new disjunction (or conjunction nodes) *again*, because otherwise your newly created nodes may violate the constraint that the operands of a conjunction/disjuntion operator cannot be conjunctions/disjunctions (respectively). And as you crawl through the tree applying deMorgan, you might end up doing various flips which require more compression passes...

So my hunch is that you'll find yourself with less repetitive code and a clearer control flow if you first parse (which often naturally produces binary trees) and then do the various transformations you in an appropriate order.

Nonetheless, there are certainly grammars which naturally produce multivalent nodes rather than binary nodes; the classic one is argument lists, but any list structure will have the same effect. Here, the list is (probably) not the result of flattening parenthetic subexpressions, though. It simply responds to a grammar such as:

```py
    @_('expr')
    def exprlist(self, p):
        return [p.expr]

    @_('exprlist "," expr')
    def exprlist(self, p):
        p.exprlist.append(p.expr)
        return p.exprlist

    @_('ID "(" exprlist ")" ')
    def expr(self, p):
        return ('call', p.ID, p.exprlist)
        # Or, if you want a truly multivalent node:
        # return ('call', p.ID) + tuple(p.exprlist)
```

SLY can do that sort of thing automatically if you give it EBNF productions, so that might only be slightly interesting.